# Dot Plot include vertical line and dots of different colors

Tags: r, lattice

I needed to include in the code below, a vertical line, 
for example, in position x = 5 and that all points smaller than 5 have another color, 
for example blue.

The values of a variable  can be read from the x-axis, and the y-axis shows the order of the observations in the variable (from bottom to top). Isolated points as the far ends, and on either side in a plot, suggest potentional outliers

Thanks

```
library(dplyr)
library(lattice)
n = 1000
df <- tibble(
  xx1 = runif(n, min = 3, max = 10),
  xx2 = runif(n, min = 3, max = 10),
  xx3 = runif(n, min = 3, max = 10)
  )

MyVar <- c("xx1","xx2","xx3")

MydotplotBR <- function(DataSelected){

  P <- dotplot(as.matrix(as.matrix(DataSelected)),
               groups=FALSE,
               strip = strip.custom(bg = 'white',
                                    par.strip.text = list(cex = 1.2)),
               scales = list(x = list(relation = "same",tck = 1,
                                      draw = TRUE, at=seq(0,10,1)),x=list(at=seq),
                             y = list(relation = "free", draw = FALSE),
                             auto.key = list(x =1)), 
               col=10, 
               axes = FALSE,
               cex  = 0.4, pch = 5,   
               xlim=c(0,10),  
               xlab = list(label = "Variable Value", cex = 1.5),
               ylab = list(label = "Order of data in the file", cex = 1.5))

  print(P)

}
(tempoi <- Sys.time())
Vertemp <- MydotplotBR(df[,MyVar])
(tempof <- Sys.time()-tempoi)
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're using dotplot for this ? the way your plot is generated makes it impossible to realize what you want. You want a color depending on the x-axis ? The x-axis is not the same in the 3 panels generated by this code.

Comment: Hello, It can be with another function.  I want that for example if the value of x  is <3, the dot has the color blue and if it is greater than or equal to 3, the dot has the color red. Thanks @RoB

Answer (score 0):

I find it weird that you want a color dependent only on the x-axis when values are also used on the y-axis of other plots.
Nevertheless, here's a homemade `pairs_cutoff()` function doing what you want.

```
pairs_cutoff <- function(data, cutoff, cols = c("red", "blue"),
                         only.lower = F, ...){
  data <- as.data.frame(data)
  cns <- colnames(data)
  nc <- ncol(data)

  layout(matrix(seq_len(nc^2), ncol = nc))

  invisible(
  sapply(seq_len(nc), function(i){
    sapply(seq_len(nc), function(j){
      if(i == j){
        plot.new()
        legend("center", bty = "n", title = cns[i], cex = 1.5, text.font = 2, legend = "")
      } else {
        if(j < i & only.lower)
          plot.new()
        else{
          if(is.null(cutoff))
            cols <- cols[1]
          plot(data[,i], data[,j], col = cols[(data[,i] < cutoff) + 1], 
               xlab = cns[i], ylab = cns[j], ...)
        }
      }


    })
  })
  )
}
```

Using your suggested data :

```
n = 1000
dat <- tibble(
  xx1 = runif(n, min = 3, max = 10),
  xx2 = runif(n, min = 3, max = 10),
  xx3 = runif(n, min = 3, max = 10)
)

pairs_cutoff(dat, cutoff = 5, only.lower = T)
```

outputs the following plot :
[image]

You can specify extra parameters to the plot function (eg. `pch`) directly to `pairs_cutoff`.
Also, if you want the full symmetric grid of plots, set `only.lower = F`.

Comment: Hello, I appreciate the attention. But dotchart, being the variable XX1, the values of a variable XX1 can be read from the x-axis, and the y-axis shows the order of the observations in the variable (from bottom to top). Isolated points as the far ends, and on either side in a plot, suggest potentional outliers.